# C# properties and how to access their values from another function/class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, properties

This is my fist attempt using properties and I've ran into a roadblock and have had a heck of time finding examples.  It may be because I'm doing this completely wrong.

I have a method that sets all the properties.

```
public class wsBase : Page
{
    public class Client
    {
        public DateTime AppointmentDate{ get; set; }
        public int TIN { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; } 
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int SSN { get; set; }
    }

    public class Patient
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The setting function:

```
public void SettingAppointmentData(int employeeID, DateTime ApptDt, DateTime patientDOB, string patientFname, string patientLname, int patientgender)
    {
        wsData wsD = new wsData();
        Client cli = new Client();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        Patient pat = new Patient();

        pat.DOB = patientDOB;

        patientFname = ValidateName(patientFname);
        patientLname = ValidateName(patientLname);

        pat.FirstName = patientFname;
        pat.LastName = patientLname;
        pat.Gender = patientgender;
     }
```

My problem lies in trying to access these set parameters.  An example of the function thats trying to access the parameters is below.  Below isnt working and I know I'm handling it wrong by what I'm seeing.  How do I access the properties set from those properties?

```
public bool eligibleAppointment()
{
        wsBase.Client cli = new wsBase.Client();
        wsBase.Employee emp = new wsBase.Employee();
        wsBase.Patient pat = new wsBase.Patient();

        DateTime DOB = pat.DOB;
        DateTime appt = cli.AppointmentDate;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks ok at first glance

Comment: You're continually creating new instances instead reusing the instances you've already created.

Comment: I'd recommend to not use nested classes if possible.

Comment: In your third code block, the `cli`, `emp`, and `pat` objects you've created are all freshly created new objects and the properties will not contain a value beyond any defaults -- for example, `cli.AppointmentDate` is most likely `DateTime.MinValue`.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Declaring a class inside another doesn't make it a *property*. Add a property to `wsBase` for ex, `public Client Client {get;set;}`

Comment: Yes, as @I4V says -- but you'll want to name it something besides Client, like: `public Client CurrentClient { get; set; }`

Comment: @Cortright  `but you'll want to name it something besides Client` Why? No need.

Comment: @DennisTraub `I'd recommend to not use nested classes if possible.` Why? what is wrong?

Comment: @I4V the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984529/c-sharp-public-nested-classes-or-better-option puts it much better than I ever could.

Comment: `public partial class SomePage : BasePage { public Foo Foo { get; set; } public class Foo { public string x { get; set; } } // more stuff....` You'll get a compiler error if you try to do this. Same as `public Client Client`

Comment: @Cortright `public Client Client { get; set; }` is fine. You can declare a property with the same property name as its type without any issues.

Comment: @Cortright `You'll get a compiler error if you try to do this.` No you wont. try this: `public class XX
        {
        }
        public class YY
        {
            public XX XX { set; get; }
        }
        `

Comment: I just put a Foo nested class in a Page, and tried to make a `public Foo Foo { get; set; }` property and got this compiler error:
The type 'JohnForm' already contains a definition for 'Foo'

Comment: If it's not nested, it works fine -- FYI.  :)

Comment: Your example works fine, but this one does not (which is what the OP was doing, with the nested classes).  You try it:
`public class YY { public class XX { } public XX XX { set; get; } }`

Comment: Obviously you can't have two members with the same name in a type; assuming you're not trying to do that, and you declare your property outside of the actual type, it works fine. :)

Comment: @aevitas -- right, that's all I am trying to say.  And I'm board with the don't use nested classes bandwagon too.

Comment: Cortright: you had issue correct.  What I was doing was creating new objects.  Is it possible to access the object properties I set in the SettingAppointmentData() function?  That's what I was trying to do from the eligibleAppointment() function but it I ended up creating new objects which didnt contain the values that were set in the SettingAppointmentData().

Comment: Would be nice if someone voted up my question :)

Comment: yep.....................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use nested classes here , 
The purpose is typically just to restrict the scope of the nested class. Nested classes compared to normal classes have the additional possibility of the private modifier (as well as protected of course).

Basically, if you only need to use this class from within the "parent" class (in terms of scope), then it is usually appropiate to define it as a nested class. If this class might need to be used from without the assembly/library, then it is usually more convenient to the user to define it as a separate (sibling) class, whether or not there is any conceptual relationship between the two classes. Even though it is technically possible to create a public class nested within a public parent class, this is in my opinion rarely an appropiate thing to implement.

Comment: Can you show an example doing what I did without nested classes?  It would be great too if you could show me an example of how to obtain the values from another function that was set using the SettingAppointmentData() function?

Comment: example would have been nice here

Comment: What I've learned from this is to not nest classes and in order to persist the instance & instance data you must pass around the instance object(s).

Comment: What I've learned from this is to not nest classes and in order to persist the instance & instance data you must pass around the instance object(s).  Above I kept on creating new objects when I should have been accessing the existing object.  Those instances can also be set/get.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool eligibleAppointment()
{
        wsBase.Client cli = new wsBase.Client();
        wsBase.Employee emp = new wsBase.Employee();
        wsBase.Patient pat = new wsBase.Patient();

        DateTime DOB = pat.DOB;
        DateTime appt = cli.AppointmentDate;
}
```

What you're doing in this code is creating new objects of your `Client`, `Employee` and `Patient` objects, and you are then assigning `Client.AppointmentDate` to `appt`. This will set that specific property to `DateTime.MinValue`, since you haven't previously assigned a value to `AppointmentDate`; it'll assume its default value which is `DateTime.MinValue` from the top of my head.

What you are really trying to do is something like this:

```
    public class Client
    {
        public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
        public int TIN { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    private Client _client = new Client();
    public bool EligibleAppointment()
    {
        _client.AppointmentDate = DateTime.Today; // Or something. This way you'll assign DateTime.Today to the AppointmentDate of this specific _client object.

        return _client.AppointmentDate > DateTime.MinValue; // Or whatever.
    }
```

This way you'll actually create an object of your `Client` class, and you can then use the setter of the `AppointmentDate` of that specific object. You can assign it any `DateTime` value you like, and re-use it later on. If you want to obtain the values from these properties (calling the *getter*), you'd simply use `_client.AppointmentDate` and do whatever you need to do with them.

What you should take into account here is the *scope* of your object declarations, and their lifespans. When for example you do the following:

```
public void Foo()
{
    var client = new Client();

    // As soon as Foo() stops executing, client will be disposed, and client.Username won't be SomeUser anymore.
    // Reason being is that it's declared on a scope local to Foo(), its lifespan is the duration of the method execution.
    client.Username = "SomeUser";
}
```

On the other hand, if you assign the `Client` object in outer scope, the data will be retained for later, like so:

```
private Client _client = new Client();

public void Foo()
{
    // Since _client is declared in the outer scope now, the data we assign to _client.Username
    // below will still be there even when Foo() finished execution.
    _client.Username = "SomeUser";
} 

public void Bar()
{
    // This'll still give us "SomeUser", since the object is still "alive" since we've called Foo().
    Console.WriteLine("Username: " + _client.Username);
}
```

You may want to read up on [how variable and method scoping works in .NET on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

On a side note, I'd personally not use nested classes in this specific implementation, simply because the enclosing type doesn't serve any purpose other than *containing* other types, which is hardly ever good practice. There's an SO article on that in one of the comments to your question I believe if you want to read up on it more.

Comment: public void SettingAppointmentData() is setting the data.  My question is how to access that data from EligibleAppointment()

Comment: You have to declare your `Client` object and the other ones in outer scope, like in my second code snippet. In both your `SettinAppointmentData`and `EligibleAppointment` you instantiate your objects on a local scope, which means that as soon as your methods finish execution, GC collects them and the data is lost. If you declare them outside of those methods they will be retained between the two function calls, and you can use the data freely. I'll update my answer to explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments about setting up your class correctly.

So you really want to do this or something like it:

```
Client cli = new Client();
Employee emp = new Employee();
Patient pat = new Patient();

public bool eligibleAppointment()
{
        cli.Client = "something";
        emp.Employee = "something";
        pat.Patient = "something";

        DateTime DOB = pat.DOB;
        DateTime appt = cli.AppointmentDate;
}
```

Hops this get you going in the right direction.

Comment: The values are already being set in the SettingAppointmentData() function.  My question was how to access those values from the eligibleAppointment() function.

Comment: And you are resetting those value to zero in this function by making a new instance of the classes, I think.

Comment: So the question is how do I get the values without setting them to zero?

Comment: As I show in the example initialize them once out side the methods and make sure you only set it in one place or reset them in one place, follow the order of events.

Comment: It seems I cannot instantiate the properties as new in the new class without overwriting the set property values.  I'm close to giving up on properties.  I'm unable to do what I was trying to do.  It looks like they have to be set and accessed only from the same function it was set with which is not what I was trying to do.

Comment: Again when and where you set the a property matters, and you should only make one instance of a class in the class consuming it.

Comment: N4TKD: I understand but unfortuantely now I'm led to researching how to pass an instance from one class to another.  It seems the only way this will work is if I share the original instance that set the property values.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class wsBase : Page
{
public Client client {get;set;}
public Employee employee {get ; set;}
public Patient patient{get;set;}
// your existing code here 
}
public bool eligibleAppointment()
{

// Write your logic here .

}
```