# Circular definition in a constant enum

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a constant of type `Enum` but I get a error..
My enum is:

```
public enum ActivityStatus
{
    Open = 1,
    Close = 2
}
```

and I have a model that uses it:

```
public class CreateActivity
{
    public int Id;
    public const ActivityStatus ActivityStatus = ActivityStatus.Open;
}
```

the following error occurs:

> Error  1   The evaluation of the constant value for 'Help_Desk.Models.CreateActivity.ActivityStatus' involves a circular definition...

But if I change the name of `ActivityStatus` property it works!

```
public class CreateActivity
{
    public int Id;
    public const ActivityStatus AnyOtherName = ActivityStatus.Open;
}
```

Why it happens?

Comment: relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211567/enum-and-property-naming-conflicts

Comment: If it hurts when you do that, stop doing that.

Comment: Very interesting. Note that if you remove `const` (possibly specifying `static` and/or `readonly` instead), it works! C# Language Specification section 7.6.4.1 applies in most cases, but why not in yours?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because the c# compiler intepretes the third `ActivityStatus` in:

```
public const ActivityStatus ActivityStatus = ActivityStatus.Open;
```

as the name of the constant being defined instead than the name of the enumeration - hence the circular reference: you are definining a constant in terms of the constant itself.

In C# you can use the same name for members and types, and usually resolve ambiguities specifying the fully qualified names (i.e. adding the namespace), but in my experience it is not a good idea, it makes code confusing: the compiler can figure out which is which, but the poor human reading the code has an hard time figuring out if a certain name refers to a class or type or member.

Comment: And the solution is to change `ActivityStatus.Open` to `Namespace.ActivityStatus.Open`

Comment: No, it is not a compiler bug - the problem is that third `ActivityStatus` can mean two things: the name of the enumeration or the name of the constant, the compiler has to pick one - and it picks the name of the constant (if @EricLippert shows up he can explain us why the compiler makes this choice...)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, that's not the solution.  Having a variable of the same name as it's type is just asking for trouble.  The solution is to change the name of the variable.

Comment: @Servy, I'm not sure all agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211567/enum-and-property-naming-conflicts

Comment: @Servy: I don't agree. There more than enough samples of this. No sign of trouble.

Comment: @murilokunze: I try to avoid it, but that's just my personal preference. It is fine to do it if you prefer - and as others pointed out above there are even example of this in the system libraries (the `System.Data.CommandType` enumeration and the `System.Data.DbCommand.CommandType` property)

Comment: It a little curious to me that the compiler (in the parser?) decides that the third `ActivityStatus` is the constant being defined.  If it were less greedy and parsed the whole statement, surely it would be valid? On the face of it, the rules are simple (probably @EricLippert would show they're not) to figure out a fallback strategy on the the assignment.  Better read the spec and see what it says.  In other places, the compiler can infer the expected behaviour, why not here?

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a variable with the same name of a class or enum.

Maybe it will work if you specify the namespace, like :

```
public class CreateActivity
{
    public int Id;
    public const TheNamespace.ActivityStatus ActivityStatus =
        TheNamespace.ActivityStatus.ActivityStatus.Open;
}
```

Comment: you can. this problem is specific to const

Comment: That's not correct. You can name your variables like classes, no problem. No downvote because using the namespace on `ActivityStatus.Open` solves the compiler error.

Comment: Well, you *can*, but you never *should*, even if there is some way to disambiguate the variable from the type when using them.

Comment: @Servy, I'm not sure all agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211567/enum-and-property-naming-conflicts

Comment: I disagree very strongly with this answer. Naming a variable the same as it's enum type is _extremely_ common and not a bad practice at all IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If private usage only: You can change ActivityStatus to readonly field and move setting of default value to constructor.

If public usage: You can use property with getter only.

In most of the code analyzers additional namespace will be treated as redundance in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid from the Circular Definition Problem in C#, You can reference/call the variable/type/member etc with full qualified name like

```
Namespace..Member/Type/ etc
```

Hope you will fix the error by now.