# Best practices naming convention for const Enum avoiding circular definition

Tags: c#, enums, naming-conventions

This is sort of a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729147/circular-definition-in-a-constant-enum), but there was no real resolution.

So here we go. Lets say I have:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
}

public class BlueUnicorn
{
    private const Color Color = Color.Blue;
}
```

1. "Use a singular name for most Enum types, but use a plural name for Enum types that are bit fields." retreived from [Microsoft's Enumeration Type Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001%28VS.71%29.aspx) **Check!**
2. "Consider giving a property the same name as its type." retreived from [Microsoft's Names of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx)
   **Check!**
3. I should be using a constant instead of readonly, according to Resharper [image]**Check!**

But I get a compiler error. It's odd though, no intellisense on this. **The evaluation of the constant value for 'BlueUnicorn.Color' involves a circular definition.**

I feel like I'm in a convention crack here. What should the field be named according to best practices naming convention?

Comment: May I suggest renaming `Color` to `ColorChoice` for either the enum or the BlueUnicorn const?

Comment: @Kane: What's the rational for this? I don't think it fits.

Comment: This is a bit off to the side -- Despite Resharper's advice, I would use readonly instead of const for any public that is not a natural constant.   (like a day or something that _never_ changes).  Reason:  consts are copied and not referenced.  So, if your code above is in ClassLibrary A, and exe B references A, and you build, the Color.Blue value is copied into exe B.  That means that if you release a new version of the class lib that changes the const value to green, your exe will continue to use blue until you recompile it as well.

Comment: (although I suppose that you could argue that Color.Blue for a BlueUnicorn _is_ a natural constant :P

Comment: @JMarsch: His constant is private.

Comment: Oh right -- yah, private const is ok.

Answer (score 4):

You can name that field just the way you do. To resolve the compilation error, simply add the namespace of the enum in front of `Color.Blue`.

Comment: @Grant: Unfortunately, yes. But that actually is a bug, because it is *not* redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You are not in a convention crack (great term by the way!). Convention (2) does not apply as that is for properties, not fields or constants. Therefore, you can call it something like `UnicornColor`.

As a side note, I appreciate that this is probably not your real code (unless you genuinely *are* writing a Unicorn simulator!), but it seems to me that having a BlueUnicorn class is not right. Having a class that is defined based on a particular constant within that class seems too specific - surely `Color` would be an attribute of a `Unicorn` class?

I've no idea if this applies to your real code, but it might be your design is a bit wrong anyway, and the question never arises?