# Does the C# compiler get the Color Color rule wrong with const type members?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, member-access

Okay, so the C# Language Specification has [a special section (old version linked)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691354.aspx) on the `Color Color` rule where a member and its type has the same name. Well-known guru Eric Lippert [once blogged](http://web.archive.org/web/20130202204339/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx) about it.

The question I am going to ask here is in a sense (not) quite the same that was asked in the thread [Circular definition in a constant enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729147/). You can go and upvote that other question if you like.

Now for my question. Consider this code:

```
namespace N
{
    public enum Color
    {
        Green,
        Brown,
        Purple,
    }

    public class C1
    {
        public const Color Color = Color.Brown;  // error CS0110 - WHY? Compiler confused by Color Color?
    }
    public class C2
    {
        public static readonly Color Color = Color.Brown;  // fine
    }
    public class C3
    {
        public static Color Color = Color.Brown;  // fine
    }
    public class C4
    {
        public Color Color = Color.Brown;  // fine
    }
}
```

The point here is that in each situation above, the right-most identifier `Color` can refer either to the `enum` type, or to the class member with the same name. But the `Color Color` rule mentioned above means that we should see if the member (`Brown`) is static or non-static. Since it is static in this case, we should interprete `Color` accordingly.

My obvious main question: **Why does this not work with a `const` type member? Is this unintended?**

(Obviously, saying `N.Color.Brown` (`N` is the namespace) "fixes" it; I am not asking about that!)

---

Side note: With local variable `const`, the above anomaly does not exist:

```
    public class C5
    {
        public Color Color;
        void M()
        {
            const Color Color = Color.Brown;  // works (no warning for not using local variable?)
        }
    }
    public class C6
    {
        public Color Color;
        void M()
        {
            const Color other = Color.Brown;  // works (warning CS0219, 'other' not used)
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the same problem with a pseudo-enum: `class Pseudo
        {
            public const Pseudo Brown = null;
        }
        class C7
        {
            public const Pseudo Pseudo = Pseudo.Brown; /* error CS0110 */
        }`

Comment: I'm not sure if the compiler gets it wrong, but interrestingly enough the intellisense thinks that it's the enum, not the constant.

Comment: Constant expressions are a big deal.  Technically the compiler could solve this problem by not yet adding the identifier to the symbol table until the entire statement is parsed.  But that affects the quality of the diagnostic for `const int bad = bad + 1;`  Now you'd get "name does not exist", that's not pretty.

Comment: Googling a little, saw a bug filed on JetBrains for the intellisense comment https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-353104 , would be interesting to see a comment there

Comment: Both enums and const are converted to literals at compile time... I feel like that must have something to do with it, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Slartibartfast Nice find!

Comment: Which compiler version are you using? I wonder if this is any different with Roslyn (VS2015) vs. earlier versions.

Comment: @JoeWhite This was done with the Visual C# compiler that comes with Visual Studio 2013, the newest released version. I agree it would be interesting to hear if this behavior is the same in the Roslyn compiler. And in older versions of Microsoft's compiler. And in other implementations, such as Mono's C# compiler.

Comment: I'm guessing it is the same in previous versions. I found this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/621384/cs0110-when-defining-constant-expression where it appears to have been reported in 2010, to which Microsoft answered 'Will Not Fix'.

Comment: @DrewJordan, I think you should post that as an answer. "circularity detection for constants is being too aggressive here" pretty much answers the question.

Comment: I'm working on one that incorporates it, sort of.

Comment: @DrewJordan Cool. I just wrote a comment on that Connect bug report, linking back here. I had not attempted to search Connect before I asked this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is a bug. I am unable to reproduce the problem in CTP 5 of VS 2015, and I think this one should have been fixed as part of the Roslyn rewrite. However, a commenter below notes that they can reproduce it in CTP 6. So I'm not sure what is going on here as far as whether this bug has been fixed or not.

On a personal note: I do not specifically recall if I was tasked with looking into this one when it was first reported back in 2010 but since I did quite a bit of work on the circularity detectors around then, odds are pretty good.

This is far from the only bug there was in the circularity detectors; it would get quite confused if there were nested generic types which in turn had generic base types whose type arguments involved the nested types.

I am not at all surprised that Alex "won't fix"ed this one; I spent quite a long time rewriting the code that did class circularity detection and the change was deemed too risky. All that work was punted to Roslyn.

If you're interested to see how the Color Color binding code works in Roslyn, take a look at the aptly-named method [`BindLeftOfPotentialColorColorMemberAccess`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs,6064cd1992013394) -- I love me some descriptive method names -- in `Binder_Expressions.cs`.

Comment: thanks Eric. Was I correct that it was using both definitions at once, and that's why it works until you use `const`?

Comment: @DrewJordan: I don't remember; I'd have to take a look at the code. Your supposition is entirely plausible though.

Comment: @EricLippert I've got a CTP 6 virtual machine, and it's not fixed there.

Comment: @Pharylon: Weird, I am running CTP 5 here and I cannot reproduce the problem. I'll make a note of it in the text.

Answer (score 13):

1) It doesn't work with a `const` because it's trying to allow both definitions (enum type and class member) at the same time, and so it tries to define itself as a function on itself.

2) Is it unintended? sort of. It's an unintended consequence to an intended behavior.

Basically, this is a bug that Microsoft acknowledges but has filed as 'Won't Fix', documented on Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/621384/cs0110-when-defining-constant-expression).

I can't find the 5.0 language spec online (in article or blog form) anywhere but if you're interested, you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all). We're interested in page 161, section 7.6.4, Member Access, and it's first section 7.6.4.1, which is the same section the OP linked to (it was 7.5.4.1 then).

The fact that you can name a member and a type the exact same name (e.g., Color) is something that was explicitly allowed, even though your identifier now has two separate meanings. Here is the spec's language:

> 7.6.4.1 Identical simple names and type names In a member access of the form E.I, if E is a single identifier, and if the meaning of E as
>   a simple-name (§7.6.2) is a constant, field, property, local variable,
>   or parameter with the same type as the meaning of E as a type-name
>   (§3.8), then both possible meanings of E are permitted. The two
>   possible meanings of E.I are never ambiguous, since I must necessarily
>   be a member of the type E in both cases. In other words, the rule
>   simply permits access to the static members and nested types of E
>   where a compile-time error would otherwise have occurred. For example:

```
struct Color {  
    public static readonly Color White = new Color(...);    
    public static readonly Color Black = new Color(...);    
    public Color Complement() {...} 
} 
class A {   
    public Color Color;                 // Field Color of type Color    
    void F() {      
        Color = Color.Black;            // References Color.Black static member                       
        Color = Color.Complement();     // Invokes Complement() on Color field  
    }   
    static void G() {       
    Color c = Color.White;          // References Color.White static member 
    } 
}
```

Here's the key part:

***both possible meanings of E are permitted. The two possible meanings of E.I are never ambiguous, since I must necessarily be a member of the type E in both cases. In other words, the rule simply permits access to the static members and nested types of E where a compile-time error would otherwise have occurred.***

When you define `Color Color = Color.Brown`, something changes. Since I (Brown) *must* be a member of E (Color) in both cases (static and not-static), this rule allows you access to both, instead of restricting one due to the current (non-static) context. However, now you've made one of the contexts (your non-static one) a constant. Since it's allowing both, it's trying to define `Color.Brown` as *both* the enum and the class member, but there's a problem with it depending on it's own value (you can't have `const I = I + 1` for example).

Comment: I upvoted (mostly because you found the Connect report (link it from this answer even if it is also in your comment to my question)). But how does your answer explain why no error comes with a non-const field (e.g. the `C2.Color` from the question) while an error comes with a `const` type member (`C1.Color`)?

Comment: I'll add the link to this answer. If I'm understanding it correctly, the compiler *would* throw an error when a member name clashes with a type name, but it's ignored on purpose because both are guaranteed to have the same fields ('I's). The compiler still can't tell the difference between the enum and the member, it just doesn't tell you that it can't and just uses both definitions. Once you define it as a `const` it still tries to use both, and the member definition makes it a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it has something to do with the fact that the value of the constant must be deterministic at compile time, but the value of the (static) property will be determined at run-time.