# Property same name as type - can i get rid of the explicit namespace?

Tags: c++-cli

This does not compile without explicit namespaces.

```
namespace A
{
public enum class Foo {};

public interface class Bar
{
public:
    property A::Foo Foo
    {
        virtual A::Foo get();
    };
};

} // namespace A
```

I used the common .NET/C# style to name the type and property identical here. The explicit namespaces are annoying, especially if they are nested/verbose in a real example.

*Can i get rid of the explicit namespaces somehow?*

Any way to "beautify" this? I tried using/typedef of the enum in the implementation of the property in the .cpp file to get the enum in the surrounding scope. No success.

Comment: C++ naming rules apply here, only C# knows how to solve the Color Color problem.  Well, [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775034/does-the-c-sharp-compiler-get-the-color-color-rule-wrong-with-const-type-members/28819495).